# Javascript: ReferenceError - On highlighting text using select() and focus()

Tags: javascript, html

What is problem with this Snippet?

Why it is not working?

```
<input type="text" id="zuhu" value="Gigubaba 2015" onClick="selectTheText(this)" />

function selectTheText(textField)  
{
  alert(textField);
  textField.focus();
  textField.select(); 
}
```

Why it says:

```
ReferenceError: selectTheText is not defined
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0c2g5a7g/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/0c2g5a7g/2/

Comment: `Wrap script in body/head`.. `selectTheText` has to be `global`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/0c2g5a7g/3/

Comment: dont need to camelcase the onclick and need the .value in the argument passed to the function ...onclick="selectTheText(this.value)"...

Comment: @gavgrif, Is that causing `selectTheText is not defined` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre: YES..... but your snippet working fine and i find no difference between both

Comment: If you open my fiddle, I have changed `LOAD TYPE` to `No wrap - in <body>`

Comment: @RayonDabre: I still not get it. Where you did that?

Comment: There is a option as `JAVASCRIPT{*(gear-icon)}`

Comment: @RayonDabre
So this is JFiddle related issue. If i will copy the same to my code. It will not happen; right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108473/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-rayon-dabre).